# Delete all files inside a Single Folder - using Terminal, as Admin

Tags: command-line, 22.04, delete, timeshift

I have Timeshift installed on Ubuntu 22.04. It has some unfinished snapshots eating too much of my disc space (close to 100 GB). I am currently using Nautilus/Files to delete them (as administrator) from `/timeshift/snapshots`. There are a 5 folders there, with names like `2023-12-02-12-15-00`, which is snapshot date and time combined.

The process of deleting all files is taking a long time (the process is still going on, 1 hour already, I have SSD) and asks for password every now and then, which is very uncomfortable.

I am wondering whether there is any safe command to delete all contents inside a folder as `sudo`. Hoping it will be faster and more effective. Any help will be great. Thanks.

**Edit:**

I browsed through Timeshift and was able to delete them all quickly. But would still like to know how to do it using Terminal. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is the `rm` command to remove files.

Open a Terminal and go to the `/timeshift/snapshots` directory:

```
cd /timeshift/snapshots
```

To delete everything (files) in the snapshots directory:

```
sudo rm *
```

To delete everything in the snapshots directory including any directories and their contents:

```
sudo rm -r *
```

Be VERY respectful of the `rm` command as it can cause you a lot of pain...

Comment: When in a directory, if any files' first character is a ".", then they will not be picked up by the "*" and be left.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /timeshift/snapshots/
ls -ltr *
```

will list contents. Check if it is the correct directory. The names in there need to match what you see in Nautilus.

Important to remember: `ls` is the list command and if `ls` shows it replacing `ls` with `rm` will remove what was shown (and what might got added in between the 2 commands ;))

```
sudo rm -rf 202[012]-*/
```

will erase all files starting with 2020, 2021, 2022 if you have directories that old.

Some examples to show how this works:

```
sudo rm -rf 2023-0?-??*/
```

will delete anything for `2023` up to `2023-09-30`(so 2023 up to and cocluding September).

```
sudo rm -rf 2023-10*/
```

will do all from October 2023. Change the last 2 to 11 for November.

You can also do autocomplete: type `sudo rm -rf 20` and then TAB to have it fill it the remainder of the file name. When you reach a point where it satisfies your need add `*/` and hit enter. It will remove all those files.

---

In case you want it ALL gone and do not care about any of the snapshots the easiest one will be:

```
cd /timeshift/
sudo rm -rf snapshots/*
```

This WILL also delete the most recent snapshot.

I used letters in the commands for a reason: if you are in the wrong directory it will likely error out as `2023` and `snapshot` are not often used.

It can take a while but it will not ask the admin password again unless 15m pass between 2 commands.